# Count the number of membership changes across multiple vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, neural-network, membership

I have 2 vectors in which elements of a similar value are considered to be of the same group, something like this:

```
V1    V2

1     7
1     8
1     8
1     8
1     9
2     10
3     11
3     11
3     11
3     12
4     12
4     12
```

In this example, **V1** has 4 groups, group 1 has the first 5 elements , group 2 has the next 1 element, group 3 has the next 4 elements, and group 4 has the last 2 elements. **V2** has 5 groups, group 1 has the first element, group 2 has the next 3 elements, etc.

Now, I would like to count the number of time an element switches groups, using **V1** as the reference. Let's consider group 1 in **V1**. The first 5 elements are in this same group. In **V2**, that's no longer the case because `V2(1,1)` and `V2(5,1)` do not have the same value as the remaining elements and thus are considered to have switched/changed membership. Applied the same principle, there is no switch for group 2 (i.e.,`V1(6,1)` and `V2(6,1)`), one switch for group 3, and no switch for group 4. Total is 3 switches.

At first I thought this would be a simple calculation with no. of switches = `numel(unique(V1)) - numel(unique(V2))`. However, as you can see, this underestimates the number of switches. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I also welcome a solution to a simpler problem in which **V1** contains only one group, like this:

```
    V1    V2

    2     7
    2     8
    2     8
    2     8
    2     8
    2     8
    2     8
    2     9
    2     8
    2     10
    2     10
    2     8
```

In this second case, the count is 4 nodes that switch: V2(1,1), V2(8,1), V2(10,1), V2(11,1).

Side note: this is actually a network problem: **V1** and **V2** are partitions and I'm trying to count the number of time a node switches membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `unique` and `accumarray`

```
    u = unique([V1 V2],'rows');
    switches  = accumarray(u(:,1) , 1, [],@numel)-1;
    total_switches = sum(switches)
```

or you can use `histcounts`

```
    u = unique([V1 V2],'rows');
    switches  = histcounts(u(:,1) , [unique(u(:,1)); u(end,1)])-1;
    total_switches = sum(switches)
```

Comment: Wow, you make it look so simple! Thank you, rahnema1!

Comment: @A.Rainer Glad if it can help!